# connect WS_FTP Server 7.1 with .net ftpRequest

Tags: .net, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file to this ftp server using System.Net.FtpWebRequest in .net 2.0, but keep getting an error:

The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Do you have any suggestions on how to figure it out? and the strange thing is I can connect it using IE6, but not IE8...

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the special thing is that IE6 uses active mode on the ftp.